# docker-compose: django, development server not listening?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I have been following along [this simple tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/) about setting up a simple django/postgres project with docker compose.
I have made some minor modifications to the `docker-compose.yml` file which now looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py runserver 9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

However when hitting `127.0.0.1:9000` on my browser I get

> This site can't be reached

Here is the terminal output:

```
Starting wdocker_db_1
Starting wdocker_web_1
Attaching to wdocker_db_1, wdocker_web_1
db_1   | LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-04-27 13:09:55 UTC
db_1   | LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
db_1   | LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   | LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
web_1  | Operations to perform:
web_1  |   Apply all migrations: sessions, contenttypes, admin, auth
web_1  | Running migrations:
web_1  |   No migrations to apply.
web_1  | No changes detected
```

and here is the `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 9000` output

`tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      15022/docker-proxy`

Comment: you need to use a postgres client to connect to the server and not the browser

Comment: You are supposed to be able to see the django project's welcome page (using a browser of course) as stated in the tutorial itself.

Comment: are you on mac or windows? you will need to use the docker-machine ip and not localhost

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to listen django on 0.0.0.0:9000 like this :

```
command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:9000"
```

Comment: Thx, that was the issue.